# How can I add a start and end date range in views exposed filter for Drupal 9 webform submission data?

Tags: views, webforms

I have created a view which displays all the webform submission data, but when it comes to views exposed filter for the dates I'm unable to find a way to add a webform submitted date as a range, I did add the dates separately giving an offset value but this isn't working as a range. is there a way to get a single date as range?

Answer (score 0):

Date data filters come with some options about how to filter them. You don't need to use two Date filters for the range, you do it on the one Date filter.

You need to choose the `Is between` Operator:

[image: Date field range filter]